# Rails choosing checkboxes inside edit view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 6 app I've got a `portfolio` model which has_many `properties`. Portfolio on edit should allow choosing (checkboxes) multiple properties to become part of it, but only from the ones that don't belong to any other portfolio.

To do so I've made some below code:

`portfolios_controller.rb`

```
  def edit
    @properties = Property.where(portfolio_id: nil)
  end
```

`_form.html.erb`

```
  <div class="field">
    <% if @properties %>
      <%= form.label :properties %>
      <%= form.collection_check_boxes, :properties, @properties, :name %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

But I'm getting an syntax error:

```
ActionView::SyntaxErrorInTemplate in PortfoliosController#edit
(..)
      <%= form.collection_check_boxes, :properties, @properties, :id, :name %>
(..)
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a comma after [`collection_check_boxes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes) since it's the method you want to call.

```
<%= form.collection_check_boxes :properties, @properties, :id, :name %>
```

Note that it is the same as

```
<%= form.collection_check_boxes(:properties, @properties, :id, :name) %>
```